# Updating a Node value in snakeyaml

Tags: snakeyaml

I have a project where I have to read a yaml file, possibly modify some of the nodes, then re-write the file (if any nodes have changed), and preserve comments in the original file.  My understanding is that to preserve comments I have to use `compose` to parse the file's contents if I want to preserve the comments in the file.  This will give me a root `Node` that I can use to retrieve the parsed values from any `Node` in the graph.

However, I have not found a way to update the values in the `Node`s in the graph, though I am probably taking a too simple view of these things.  I was trying to retrieve a `Node` and then update it's value directly.  Retrieving a particular `Node` is simple.  But updating the value is not.

Are there any pointers as to how to go about this?  Or have I, perhaps, taken the wrong approach from the beginning?  I have found very few examples online of using `Node` objects directly so I don't know if what I want to do is even possible.